# $f'(x_0)\geq \frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Assuming that $f\in\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\max f'(x)=f'(x_0)$, then why $$  f'(x_0)\geq \frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x} ? $$
It might be a silly question, but I'm stuck. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Try using the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

This is mean value theorem :

There is $c=c_{x,x_0}\in (x_0,x)$ s.t. $$f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(c)(x-x_0)\leq f'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$
The claim follow.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \gt x_0$:

$f(x)-f(x_0)= \int_{x_0}^{x} f'(t)dt \le$

$ \int_{x_0}^{x}f'(x_0)dt =(x-x_0)f'(x_0);$

Let $x  < x_0:$

Proceed analogously.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, $f(x_0)-f(x)/(x_0-x)$ is the finite difference approximation to the derivative of f, and since the maximum of the derivative of f exists at $x_0$, then $f^{'}(x_0) >= f(x_0)-f(x)/(x_0-x)$ follows. The approximation of the derivative of the function f will always be less than or equal to the maximum value of the derivative of f.